# Suddenly ClassDefNotFoundException on live Google App Engine Java

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

Suddenly I'm getting a

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.project.gae.dao.PMF
```

The funny thing is (although I don't think it's that funny) it only happens once in a while, I haven't done a new deploy to app engine, sometimes it just throws this exception and other times it doesn't.

I've created the project in maven with the google app engine plugin for maven v.0.9.4 and it always used to work. Is this a known problem on the platform? I surely hope not since this would leave GAE/J completely useless for me to use in the future.

PMF is my persistenceManagerFactory class and it's written according to the official google app engine documentation, localy it always works but when I push it to the live environment it sometimes work... I have no clue what this might causing, so if anyone can help me out it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError is not necessarily "Class not found". See http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Comment: this helped me a lot... what happened was that the maven plugin also needed an extra dependency to correctly deploy